# Enable clipboard in automated tests with selenium webdriver with Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, gruntjs

How to enable/allow clipboard permission popups in automated tests with Selenium web driver, Javascript, and grunt?

[image]

Both of the arguments `--enable-clipboard` , `--enable-clipboard-features` in below code do not take any effect

```
import { Builder, Capabilities } from 'selenium-webdriver';

const chromeOptions = {
  // args: ['--enable-clipboard']
  args: ['--enable-clipboard-features']
};

const driver = await new Builder()
  .withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome())
  .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
  .build();
```

Below code doesnt work either

```
 capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': { 'desiredCapabilities/goog:chromeOptions/prefs/profile.content_settings.exceptions.clipboard', {
            '[*.],*': { last_modified: '1576491240619', setting: 1 },
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you aren't not in incognito mode because clipboard permission could not be granted in incognito.

Second, you need to open an url before enabling clipboard permission

To enable clipboard (and another permissions) in Chrome, Selenium has a special endpoint `setPermission()`. Here is the working code to enable clipboard permission

```
await driver.setPermission('clipboard-read', 'granted');
await driver.setPermission('clipboard-write', 'granted');
```

You can wrap it in a function then call it after opening an url to enable clipboard for that site

If your linting tool (tslint in this case) complaining about non-existent `setPermission()` method, you can just ignore it by adding this code before the `setPermission()` line

```
// @ts-ignore
```